# FTP upload: possible to restrict for only static content

Tags: apache, ftp

for realtime online tournaments i upload a bunch of html pages, generated by our tournament software. On the webserver i do the things with these files which are needed to do. So the tournament software is "integrated" in our website.

Now we want other people run these tournaments and then they do have to upload these generated html/css files. Via http upload it really is too much work en takes too much time.

I wanted to create another ftp account with only acces to the tournament directory. So far so good.

But, i want to limit the uploading filetypes just to html and css files, so they can only upload static content via ftp (i am just paranoid, i do not want they can upload php files with possible dangerous code or other unxpected filetypes)

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are just sequences of bytes, the extension has nothing to do, the danger is the way you read them. You must set the uploaded files to be non-executable and you are safe. Even if you set .css files to be uploaded somehow, you cannot check if it is safe or not by only extension, the attacker may have changed the extension by hand. Also, uploading PHP files will not be problem, if you specify an upload folder that Apache does not know, i.e not below your www folder.

Comment: thank you, your remark about an ftp folder outside a via http accesible folder will do the trick? I suppose i can reach that file with php-page and then extract the data as i usally do?

Comment: @Terradon yes, it will not be executable by Apache then, and you can read the contents of the files, copy them rename them from PHP easily, they will not be exposed to public.